# Google Doc to PDF 1pt (0.01in) lines do not show up

Tags: pdf, google-docs

I have been struggling with Google Doc formatting for some time now. I cannot find any know issues or other documentation on this, but then that might be my search terms all bad. I have been creating a file in Google Docs and then converting it to PDF. The issue is that when I create the PDF some of my lines go missing. When I have the lines defined in my Google Doc as 0.01in in height they look like the following in Google Docs, Image 1. Then when I download to PDF they disappear and the resulting PDF looks like Image 2. And the only way that I can get it to work is if I use 0.02in lines for the approval area as seen in Image 3. For some reason the Employee section is not causing any issues and in all the below images that area has 0.01in line heights. Help here would be greatly appreciate.

**Image 1:** (Google doc view)

[image: Google Doc with 0.01in lines]

**Image 2:** (PDF with missing Lines)

[image: PDF with Missing Lines]

**Image 3:** (0.02in lines)

[image: Approval Signatures with 0.02in lines]

Comment: What PDF viewer(s) have you viewed the PDF with? This is a common issue with some viewers with very thin horizontal or vertical lines that are not aligning with the resolution of the screen pixels.

Comment: @KevinBrown I have been downloading the file and opening it in Google Chrome. It does not change when I open the file via Adobe Acrobat. The issue also appears the same on both Windows and on Mac

Comment: So I am missing it, it does not work in everything or does work in somethings?
Also print it and is there a line or not a line coming from your printer?